# ¿Al realizar una petición desde un formulario HTML a una página PHP como guardar el estado de las variables?

Tags: php, html, formularios

Estoy realizando ejercicios de PHP, a través de un formulario ejecuto un código PHP, cuando el usuario realicé 4 intentos, no podrá volver a ejecutar el código.

El caso es que tras ejecutar el primer intento no se guarda el estado de las variables, se recarga la página, aún no he realizado conexiones a base de datos para guardas estados.

He probado con target_black, la función header(location:"") pero con todas el contador vuelve a cero alguna solución.

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h3>¡Para abrir la caja fuerte se requiere de un código!</h2>
    <!--  -->
    <form action="Programa5b.php" method="post" target="_blank">
        <label for="cajero">"Introduzca el código de acceso: "</label>
        <input type="text" name="cajero">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
<?php
    $_contador = 0;
    if ($_REQUEST['cajero'] == 2012 && $_contador < 4) {
        echo "La caja fuerte se ha abierto satisfactoriamente.";
        $_contador == 4;
    }
    else if ($_contador == 4) {
        echo "La caja se ha bloqueado, se requiere de llave maestra para abrirla.";
    }
    else {
        $_contador += 1;
        echo "Lo siento, esa no es la combinación. <br>";
        echo "Te quedan " . (4 - $_contador) . " intentos.<br>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: Podrías enviar los intentos con un `<input type="hidden">` pero el usuario podría modificarlo; mejor opción sería utilizar variables de sesión, pero con cerrar y abrir de nuevo del navegador se saltarían esa protección. Necesariamente necesitas implementar persistencia en el servidor y una base de datos es la opción más común. Así que vas a tener que ponerte con ello...

Comment: Gracias  por la información de verdad muchas gracias.

Comment: puedes realizar lo que te comenta david con el input hidden, para no hacer uso de base de datos lo que haria es encriptar el contador de intentos en el input (asi evitas que el usuario lo modifique) y en php lo decodificas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes utilizar las `COOKIES` para guardar tu variable `contador`, de esta manera, aunque el usuario actualice la página este valor seguirá siendo el mismo, a no ser que el usuario elimine las cookies de su navegador, o te las bloquee, pero es una buena solución. también puedes utilizar la `SESION` y guardarla en la misma, con lo que obtendrás un resultado parecido a utilizar `COOKIES`. En caso de que quieras que el usuario no pueda manipular esto, lo tendrás que guardar en la base de datos.

**COOKIES**

```
<?php
    if (isset($_COOKIE['contador'])) {
        if ($_REQUEST['cajero'] == 2012 && $_COOKIE['contador'] < 4) {
            echo "La caja fuerte se ha abierto satisfactoriamente.";
            $_COOKIE['contador'] == 4;
        } else if ($_COOKIE['contador'] == 4) {
            echo "La caja se ha bloqueado, se requiere de llave maestra para abrirla.";
        } else {
            $_COOKIE['contador'] += 1;
            echo "Lo siento, esa no es la combinación. <br>";
            echo "Te quedan " . (4 - $_COOKIE['contador']) . " intentos.<br>";
        }
    } else {
        setcookie('contador', $contador);
    }
    ?>
```

Lo primero que haces es mirar si la cookie está establecida, en tal caso procedes a hacer lo que hacías en tu ejemplo, pero modificando la variable `$contador`, por la `COOKIE`. En caso de que no esté estableciada, la vas a crear y pasar el valor de tu variable `$contador`.

El ejemplo es algo para encaminarte, el cual seguramente tengas que modificar para adaptarlo a tu caso.

Comment: Vale es otra forma de guardar estados, te lo agradezco para ir tirando con los ejercicios del ciclo superior me vale gracias saludos, feliz semana.